# How to pipe a sample log message manually to logstash for processing

Tags: linux, monitoring, netcat

I have set-up an ELK server in testing environment. I intend to send log messages from different clients to ELK, but first i want to test it from localhost to verify it running properly.

Previously i had directly , used a python library to interact with elastic-search (since there was a problem in using urllib2 , 400 bad request) , but this time i want to send the message to log-stash and let the log-stash deal with it before it goes to Elastic Search.

I used netcat , but there is some problem with the port number:

```
  echo "access denied" | nc localhost 5514
  Ncat: Connection refused.
```

Seems like there is nothing on this port. The logstash service is running.

Comment: Fixed it , i figured out the correct port and it works now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `logger` with the `-P` switch to set your port to 5514.

Check `man logger` for other suitable switches, eg `-t`.

```
echo "access denied" | logger -t myservice -P 5514
```

To check if port 5514 is currently associated with logstash, `lsof -i :5514`, or check logstash startup logs (meta!). Are you certain your logstash is using that particular port?